# JSON data won't be displayed via jQuerys getJSON()

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

The following code should display the `id` out of the JSON-object, which I got from a server. I cant find the mistake, could somebody help me? Thank you in advance!

The JSON-object which is returned when `http://localhost:8387/nscalemc/rest/mon/resourcestatus.json` is called:

```
{
    "groupStatus": [
        {
            "id": "Application Layer Configuration-ApplicationLayer",
            "time": 1332755316976,
            "level": 0,
            "warningIds": [],
            "errorIds": []
        },
        {
            "id": "Application Layer-ApplicationLayer:nscalealinst2",
            "time": 1333431531046,
            "level": 0,
            "warningIds": [],
            "errorIds": []
        },
        {
            "id": "Application Layer-ApplicationLayer:nscalealinst1",
            "time": 1333431531046,
            "level": 1,
            "warningIds": [
                "documentarea.locked"
            ],
            "errorIds": []
        },
        {
            "id": "Storage Layer-StorageLayerInstance1",
            "time": 1331208543687,
            "level": 0,
            "warningIds": [],
            "errorIds": []
        }
    ]
}
```

My HTML file `gadget.html`:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Monitor</title>
    <link href="css/gadget.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/gadget.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

My JavaScript file "gadget.js":

```
fetch_JSON();

function fetch_JSON() {
    var url = "http://localhost:8387/nscalemc/rest/mon/resourcestatus.json";

    $.getJSON(url+'?callback=?', function(data) {
        $(data.groupStatus).each(function() {
            $('#content').append('<p>ID: ' + $(this).id+ '</p>');
        });
    });
}
```

**EDIT:**
Thank you for your solutions! I debugged via Firebug and found out, that the getJSON-call ends with status "401 unauthorized"..

Comment: btw: is '?callback=?' needed in the getJSON method?

Comment: Are you sure your function is being executed? maybe you should put an alter inside you function fetch_JSON() { alert('here'); } just to be sure

Comment: No - only for JSONP requests. You can remove it.

Comment: No, dont know what the function of '?callback=?' would be

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should do

```
    $('#content').append('<p>ID: ' + this.id+ '</p>');
```

fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/JaxpC/

EDIT - of course you should use the ready handler to make sure thatthe dom is present (i don't think that's your case because there i an ajax call involved, but better be sure

```
$(function() {
   var url = "http://localhost:8387/nscalemc/rest/mon/resourcestatus.json";

    $.getJSON(url+'?callback=?', function(data) {
        $(data.groupStatus).each(function() {
            $('#content').append('<p>ID: ' + this.id+ '</p>');
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: ty for the solution, i've changed it, but it seems that the functions in getJSON won't be executed. i debugged it via firebug and "$(data.groupStatus).each(function() {" wasn't called..

Comment: @P4tR but in firebug (under the net panel) do you see the call end with 200 status?

Comment: ahh, i didn't know about that panel.. the call ends with "401 unauthorized"

Comment: @P4tR are you returning jsonp?

Comment: okay, i've got the solution.. the problem was, that i have to add a request header with username and pw.. but still thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

You are running the script immediately and have placed it before the div. `#content` doesn't exist when you try to append data to it.

Move the script to just before `</body>`.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan This is correct, but he is making an AJAX call, he's not attaching an event, so i don't think that the problem lies there

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

fetch_JSON();

function fetch_JSON() {
    var url = "http://localhost:8387/nscalemc/rest/mon/resourcestatus.json";

    $.getJSON(url+'?callback=?', function(data) {
        $(data.groupStatus).each(function() {
            $('#content').append('<p>ID: ' + this.id+ '</p>');
        });
    });
}
});
```